# How to download file using guzzle and forward it to response without saving locally

Tags: php, laravel, api, guzzle

I'm using Laravel and I want to get files from api (with providing token and some headers) then forward it directly to the response without saving the file locally.

Currently I'm doing it like this:

```
$response = $client->get($requestUrl, [
        'query' => [
            'hash' => $hash
        ],
        'headers' => [
            '_token_' => $oauthConfig['api_token'],
            '_token_issuer_' => 1
        ],
        'stream' => true,
    ]);

    $type = $response->getHeader('Content-Type')[0];
    $body = $response->getBody();

    $response = new StreamedResponse(function () use ($body) {
        while (!$body->eof()) {
            echo $body->read(1024);
        }
    });

    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', $type);

    return $response;
```

But I'm getting this exception:

```
LogicException
The content cannot be set on a StreamedResponse instance.
```

Any help / guidance is greatly appreciated!
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the right thing to do is

http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/psr7.html

```
use GuzzleHttp\Stream\Stream;



$response = $client->get($requestUrl, [
        'query' => [
            'hash' => $hash
        ],
        'headers' => [
            '_token_' => $oauthConfig['api_token'],
            '_token_issuer_' => 1
        ],
        'stream' => true,
    ]);

$result = '';
while(!$response->getBody()->eof()){
   $result .= $response->getBody()->read(8192);
}

$filename = 'test.gif';
return response()->streamDownload(function () use ($result) {
    echo $result;
}, $filename);
```

Comment: Call to undefined method GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response::eof()

Comment: I'm getting ����JFIF��C instead of image file in response

Comment: Still I'm getting ��JFIF��C !"$"$��C���"�������y��<�a� �d%�hI��B4hh�)xҴ.Drҗ-#1$F�����"��30,vI%�*�+g%)b�c#�,��L���tJ�d��\��[;R�M�)k�#1mc'I�'Q� ��60�R�A�^G���1B�#H�X�3@XIK!��x%%�,��aJ�dE

Comment: How can I send it to response for download? @Hackimov

Comment: return Response::download($result);

Comment: for using Response::download(), the result should be file. @Hackimov